# update prepared statement is not commiting

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc-odbc

I have this java code, and unfortunately the changes made by the update are not being propagated to the mySQL database:

```
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("update schema.t1 inner join 
                    schema.t2  on (t1.id=t2.id)" +
                   " set t1.a=t2.a, t1.b=t2.b" );


            int r = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("execute update result = "+r);
            preparedStatement.close();
            con.commit();
            con.close;
```

If i enable the auto-commit the query, indeed, works; however with the manual commit is not propagating the changes to the database (i manually check and no update is made select * from schema.t1 where a is not null).

Any ideas of what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your preparedStatement after your commit. So change this:

```
preparedStatement.close();
con.commit();
```

To this:

```
con.commit();
preparedStatement.close();
```